# Website Solution in Multi-developer environment

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 than contains multiple class library projects and one Web Site project (not a Web Application project).  Also, the Web Site project needs to run in local IIS (it won't run in IIS Express) and needs to run with debugging enabled.

Currently, I am binding to a domain which is configured on our corporate DNS server (something like `wwww.mysite.bill`) and all works great.  However, because it's bound to a domain name that points only to my computer, other developers on my team can't use the same solution.

How can I setup a solution that can be used by multiple developers?

Comment: have you tried editing the host file to point to local machine for this site on other developer's machine?

Comment: In a situation like this, we use entries in the HOSTS file to define the equivalent of a DNS entry for either a local development instance of the site such as: `127.0.0.1 local.mysite.bill` or some shared instance on the network such as: `192.168.0.100 test.mysite.bill`.

Comment: Yes, I considered adding entries to the host file but what hoping for a more Visual Studio oriented solution; one less step to setup new developers.

Comment: How about you bind it to localhost? Then just deploy it to the correct site when you deploy? Or stop using web site "projects" period.

Comment: I would love to stop using web site projects but my front-end developer likes the dynamic compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Guanxi and David for your comments; they really helped.

Below are the steps I took to setup a shared web site solution:

- Added a new entry `wwww.mysite.dev` and `127.0.0.1` to our corporate DNS
  service (alternatively this can also be done in the hosts file on each dev machine)
- Added `wwww.mysite.dev` binding to my website in IIS (this must be the first
  binding)
- Added `wwww.mysite.bill` binding to my website in IIS (so others can access my site)
- Removed my old `wwww.mysite.bill` web site from my solution in Visual Studio
- Added an existing web site `wwww.mysite.dev` to my solution via Local IIS in
  Visual Studio
- Re-added references to other projects in my solution
- Shared my solution file with other developers.